# What are some useful utils when using Gentoo Linux?

Tags: linux, gentoo, utilities

I want to make a list of utilities that come in handy in Gentoo? What tools and commands do you use and consider helpful in administration of a Gentoo system/server?

Comment: ok, re-opened. But do try to play like you're on "Jeopardy" -- phrase it in the form of a question!

Comment: I think you've swapped the descriptions of "equery" and "eclean".

Comment: I have removed the list from the question to keep it simple and clear.

Answer (score 3):

**`eclean`**

- Utility for cleaning distfiles and
  binary packages.
- Usage example: eclean distfiles
- Usage example output: Cleans out the files in /usr/portage/distfiles.  Pretty handy.

**`eix`** includes some neat obsolete checks like `eix-test-obsolete` which checks for bad entries in the /etc/portage/package.* files.

Answer (score 3):

[`dispatch-conf`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=3&chap=4#doc_chap1) for handling modified configuration files.

Answer (score 3):

- **`eix-sync`**

  Since `eix-test-obsolete` was mentioned here, apart from `eix` itself, I thought I'd write a recommendation. This is the only way I sync my portage nowadays: It performs a sync, updates the `eix` database and prints out a diff all in one go. I recommend invoking it as `eix-sync -C '-q'`, which suppresses the typically verbose output of `emerge --sync`.

  Package: `app-portage/eix`, of course :)
- **`q`**, together with its plugins such as `quse`, `qlop` or `qsize`

  Very useful set of portage-related functions, that can give similar information to `equery` and more. Part of `app-portage/portage-utils`.
- **`quickpkg`**

  A part of the core `sys-apps/portage`. Very helpful for building a tarball from an installed package if you want to temporarily downgrade/upgrade it for testing purposes. You get back to the packaged version using the `-K` (*capital* "K") switch to `emerge`. Tip: use `quickpackage --include-config=y` to include current configuration files in the package.
- **`demerge`**

  Lets you save the current list of installed packages in case you'd later want to revert. Kind of a "system checkpointing" tool.

  Package: `app-portage/demerge`

Answer (score 2):

**`rc-update`**

- utility for adding stuff in the boot list, allows different "runlevels" (priorities)
- usage example: rc-update -s shows the currectly active boot list
- usage example: rc-update add script_from_init_d default

Answer (score 1):

The `portage-utils` suite with the `q` tool and it's many aliases. It gives you much information on things like which files are in a package, what use flags are used, their descriptions and much more. Quite indispensible.

For configuration file updating, my tool of choice is dispatch-conf, which is part of the standard portage install and saves a lot of work updating unchanged config files compared to etc-update.

Answer (score 1):

I hope everybody uses it nowadays, but **`eselect`** is a must. It's pretty much *the* tool to handle which software version, which binutils, which toolchain, which opengl, which whatever you use.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I stopped using Gentoo, but apart from all the utilities
already suggested I used to like [`localepurge`](http://gentoo-portage.com/app-admin/localepurge/). It basically frees up disk space on the system by deleting unnecessary locale files and man pages.

[Small use guide.](http://bluev.wordpress.com/2005/12/27/how-to-use-localepurge/)